# SQL query to count all occurences that start with a substring

Tags: sql

Suppose that I have the following table:

```
ID:   STR:
01    abc
02    abcdef
03    abx
04    abxy
05    abxyz
06    abxyv
```

I need to use an SQL query that returns the `ID` column and the occurrences of the corresponding string as a prefix for string in other rows. E.g. The desired result for the table above:

```
ID:   OCC:
01    2
02    1
03    4
04    3
05    1
06    1
```

Comment: What database engine and version are you using?

Comment: @Lamak: I prefer a dialect independent query, otherwise, I'm using Pgsql 8.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `JOIN` the table with itself and `GROUP BY` the ID to get you the result.

```
SELECT   t1.ID, COUNT(*)
FROM     ATable t1
         INNER JOIN ATable t2 ON t2.Str LIKE t1.Str + '%'
GROUP BY
         t1.ID
```

**Some notes:**

- You want to make sure you have an index on the `Str` column
- Depending on the amount of data, your DBMS might choke on the amount it has to handle. **Worst case**, you are asking for the **SQR(#Rows)** in your table.

Comment: Thanks, the query seems to be working, but the execution seems to be extremely slow!

Comment: @banx, besides adding an index, there is not much else (I know of) you could do to speed things up. For the example you've given, you have 6 rows where the result is a group by of 12 rows. If that is average for your entire table, you can expect the DBMS having to handle twice the amount of rows before it can start grouping the results. I would expect it to be even more.

Comment: that was an example only, but the table size consists of ten of thousands of rows. I think I'll have to filter out rows before executing the query.

Comment: @banx, as I said, *worst case* is SQR of the amount of rows. For 10k rows, that would be 100mil rows your DBMS has to juggle with. For 50k rows, it would be 2.5bil rows... . This **is** worst case but it's something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

Can can do that in SQL Server's T-SQL with the following code. **Caution: I do not guarantee how this will perform though with a large dataset!**

```
Declare @Table table
    (
      Id int,
      String varchar(10)
    )

Insert  Into @Table
        ( Id, String )
Values  ( 1, 'abc' ),
        ( 2, 'abcdef' ),
        ( 3, 'abx' ),
        ( 4, 'abxy' ),
        ( 5, 'abxyz' ),
        ( 6, 'abxyv' )

Select  t.Id,
        t.String
From    @Table as t
        Inner Join @Table as t2 On t2.String Like t.String + '%'
Order By t.Id

Select  t.Id,
        Count(*) As 'Count'
From    @Table as t
        Inner Join @Table as t2 On t2.String Like t.String + '%'
Group By t.Id
Order By t.Id
```